# How do you convert NSF OpenTopography point cloud color data to RGB values?

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, point-clouds

I am working on a small project where I am attempting to display NSF OpenTopography data in a point cloud visualization using three js.  I have been successful in plotting the data points, however I am having issues with understanding the color values associated with the point cloud data.  The data includes red, green and blue channels, but the values are 5 digits long for each.

**Example:**

**Red Channel**: 16896

**Green Channel**: 17408

**Blue Channel**: 19456

How do I convert these to appropriate RGB values scaled from 0-255?

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: you need to find the range of your data; probably through some specification file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 256: [66, 68, 76]

If everything is too dark, divide by 128: [132, 136, 152]

Comment: Thanks, is it better to divide by 256 instead of 255?